# use custom pattern with picker in a dataTime field xPages

Tags: xpages

I am trying to add a dateTime edit box in an xPage and I would like to show the date and time
with a specific pattern that I define. The pattern is "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm". The date and time
appear in the desirable format when I open the xPage. The problem is caused when I select the checkbox "Use date/time picker pop-up". After this change, the time is not displayed correctly. It is always 00:00. Is this a bug? Or do I need to configure differently the edit box in order to use the pattern I want and be able to add a data/time picker properly?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's bug. I have reported it to IBM support.

You could use ExtLib Dojo Date and Time controls. There the problem is that there is a separate control for Date and Time and there is no built in way to save them in same item on document. You can do it with some SSJS though.

I have used a reqular Date/Time Edit Box ja ExtLib *Dojo Time Text Box*. The edit box is set to show date only and bound to my Date/Time field on datasource form. The Dojo Time Text Box gets its default value from the same Date/Time item on document.

In data source *querySaveDocument* event I have this code which adds the time to the date selected in date edit box:

```
// When time field is empty we get Java Date.
var dtDate:java.util.Date = getComponent("inpDT").getValue();
var dtTime = getComponent("djTime").getValue();
if (typeof dtTime == "lotus.domino.local.DateTime") dtTime = dtTime.toJavaDate()

// Combine date and time.
if (dtDate != null && dtTime != null) { 
    var dtDateTime:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(dtDate);
    dtDateTime.setLocalTime(dtTime.getHour(), dtTime.getMinute(), 0, 0);
    dominoDocument.replaceItemValue("DT", dtDateTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Panu! I have tried it with SSJS as you suggest, but the problem is that when I open a document and I split the dateTime field into two separate edit boxes in the xPage, the values are not editable anymore. The other method that I have tried is to set the values of the edit boxes through the default value. However, default value is only computed once onLoad of the xPage and doesn't change for every document through partial refreshes. Can you tell me how you have achieved to set the values of the date and time edit boxes through SSJS and be editable?

Comment: We also managed to do it with SSJS. Thank you again for your answer!